# Taking input of strings with white spaces

Tags: c++

I am trying to input strings which may contain white spaces.The entire string can be made of white spaces.
Here is what I am doing-

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
char arr[1000][1000];
int main()
{
    int t,m=3,n=2;

    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string str;        
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            getline(cin,str);
            cout << str[0] << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here t is no of test cases.
Say for m=3, I have this input-

```
1
#T
--
--
```

For visibility, `-` is used to represent white spaces.In actual input,there are white spaces instead of `-` . 
This is the output I get-

```
NUL
#
-
```

Another thing which I tried is this-

```
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        cin >> arr[i][j];
}
```

where m=3,n=2 for the example above.But printing this arr gives me following output-

```
#T
NULNUL
NULNUL
```

I am not sure why I am getting this output.Why am I getting `NUL` instead of white spaces.Also in the first code, the output I get is `NUL` before `#` ,why is that?

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Considering `NUL` isn't a thing in C++, I'd say it's based on how you're defining/initializing `str`.

Comment: @erip I have added my entire code

Comment: @OldProgrammer Done. Please have a look

Comment: First of all: [**Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to write such a complicated code to obtain whitespaces from `cin`. You can just take an advantage of `std::noskipws` flag.

**Solution 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    char x;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cin >> noskipws >> x;
        str += x;
    }
    cout << str;
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/9jcle)

---

**Solution 2:**

or even simpler, without any `string`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[10];
    cin.read(str, sizeof(str));
    cout << str;
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/267e)

---

**Solution 3:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << str;
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/6awj)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `str[0]` - this is not a string, this is a single character. When your string is empty, the only thing it contains is null-terminator (`'\0'`). And when you access the first element of your string with `[]`, you are accessing this null-terminator. And since you are printing it as a character, you see NUL as your output.

Comment: But my string is not empty. It contains two white spaces in this particular space.So printing str[0] should actually print a single white space.

Comment: Well, it does not. You've read an empty string. You can verify by printing the whole string, not just the first character.

Comment: See `cin >> noskipws >> x;` in the answer. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttf4txbf.aspx, "By default, **skipws** is in effect."